# Github actions will not push automatically to Heroku anymore after deleting/re-creating Heroku app :(

Tags: github, heroku, github-actions, psycopg2

I have a Github repository with files in it, and had Github actions setup so that it would push automatically to Heroku when pushing to main.

However, due to an issue with my database, I ended up deleting the whole Heroku app, remade a new one with the same name, got a new auth token for it, connected it back to Github, and now when I push to main, nothing pushes to Heroku at all :(

Is there any way to fix this? Any more information I can provide on how to fix this?

Basically I'm just not sure if maybe Github has an issue where it cannot connect to a fresh Heroku app or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY So for anyone who is wondering- it turned out that in my frontend (React), there was a single error and that was causing the whole thing to fail when uploading.